# Would this C# delta time loop be good for running a simulation at 60fps on server side?

Tags: c#, server, game-loop, delta

For running a simulation on the server side at 60 logic updates per second, do you think the following would suffice/be stable enough? It's not real-time physics but a mild action RPG type of multiplayer game. I don't think the Thread.Sleep is a good idea from what I've read, but not sure how else to keep it from eating up unnecessary CPU cycles in this loop.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long fps = 60;
        long interval = 1000 / fps * 10000;
        long ticks, delta;
        long prevTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        long accum = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            delta = (ticks - prevTicks);
            prevTicks = ticks;

            accum += delta;
            if (accum >= interval)
            {
                // update logic
                Console.WriteLine(accum);

                accum -= interval;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how long it takes to draw a frame to the screen, and how long it takes to run the logic for that loop, and other things.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't mention that there won't be any rendering at all. Console only.

Comment: How can you have 60FPS, "frames per second", without any rendering of a frame? Even if you're "drawing" on the console, that's rendering.

Comment: Question updated to remove the "fps" part of it. It's updating the game logic 60 times per second.

Comment: You would probably get better answers at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience using the "Accumulator" is only good in physics simulations, The accumulator make the simulation's physics more accurate but at the price of more janky rendering when the loop is running slowly (On less fps), I'd also suggest to use doubles instead of longs.